# How to get user accessible queues in YARN?

Tags: api, hadoop-yarn, apache-ranger

I use typical stack YARN/Ranger with atomic policies for accessing YARN queues. Having Hadoop user access, how to get list of queues that user has access to? I can see how it's usually done from admin side, but what about user? I went through yarn APIs, but found nothing. Ranger - user usually doesn't have enough permissions to get more details about itself. Is the only way to do it is to bruteforce all queues in cluster until u find accessible one?

Comment: Are you using Capacity Scheduler or Fair Scheduler?

Comment: @tk421 I use fair scheduler

Comment: Do you use Ambari or Cloudera Manager?

Comment: Ambari, but I'm working via yarn apis

Comment: Not with YARN APIs but https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/33234/how-to-export-all-hdp-configuration-files-xmlprope.html might help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the user queue policy is not visible through the REST APIs for Fair Scheduler.  You can double-check by running:

```
curl RM-ADDR:PORT/ws/v1/cluster/scheduler
```

but looking at [ResourceManager REST API’s:Cluster Scheduler API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Scheduler_API) I think you're out of luck.

If you use Ambari or Cloudera Manager, those might have APIs that will allow you to download the Fair Scheduler's XML file.